Thanks for sticking with me, even if I'm grumpy about specific (abusive) users
Just what the title says: we had an influx of questions of a user asking the same question again and again without really caring for previous answers they got, instead using multiple sockpuppet accounts. And I got (unreasonably) upset about that, I guess.
Thanks for being nice folks with me! And thanks for helping keeping this site alive and well-working and well self-moderated and well mod-moderated.
